# Is “I, you and he have committed a crime” correct?

Tags: grammaticality, subject-verb-agreement

Could you tell me if the following sentence is correct and why?

> 1. I, you and he have committed a serious crime.

I was giving a test which gave this solution and the explanation that 1st person pronoun comes before 2nd and 3rd. What would be the correct sentence?

Why can't it be “He, you and I”?

Comment: Sentence 2 is ungrammatical the verb should agree with its nearest antecedent, in this case "he" even if the subject is a compound, it sounds wrong to hear or say "**he have**", it's more normal to say **he has**. Where did you see or read that "he, you and I" is supposedly wrong?

Comment: I was giving a test which gave this solution and the explanation that 1st person pronoun comes before 2nd and 3rd.What would be the correct sentence?

Comment: That is what I thought.

Comment: Name the book, if the test came from a book. Specify if the answer was given by a teacher and whether they are a native speaker. If this came from a website, add the link to the source. Add this information and clarification IN the question, not in a comment. Did you see I included your comment in the question. More details makes this a more interesting and useful question.

Comment: Strictly speaking "I, you and he have..." is not ungrammatical but it's certainly weird phrasing. **You and I have...** is fine, as is **You and I with John have...***

Comment: I think this is a known awkwardness in English. Joint possessives - 'her and my car' - are similar. In order to avoid saying "I, you and he" we will use "You and I and he" or "he and I and you", both of which sound better. Or if we can possibly use "The three of us" we will. Or "[name], you and I", if the third person's name is known.